# Selecting and ordering messages from database

Tags: mysql

If trying to select all the messages in a database and display it to the users of my site.

The messages are getting selecting and grouped, but the recent message within each group of user_id's the message is always the first message sent.

My current code is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM users_messages 
WHERE message_sender=? OR message_receiver=? 
GROUP BY message_receiver 
ORDER BY message_id DESC
```

It's the first message the user ever sent that is being displayed but I would like the most recent to be selected within the group of user.

I'm getting all the users messages and the rows of the users are sorted by the most recent Conversation.

But within the recent conversation it selects the first message sent in the conversation

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: "*but the recent message within each group of user_id's the message is always the first message sent*", where it should be....?

Comment: You should learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: I need it to  display the most recent message from the specific user. Also i will take a look at prepared statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a correlated subquery like this:

```
SELECT um.* FROM user_messages um 
WHERE um.message_id IN 
(
   (SELECT MAX(message_id) FROM users_messages WHERE 
    message_sender=? OR 
    message_receiver=? GROUP BY message_receiver)
)
ORDER BY um.message_id DESC
```

Comment: No sorry. My querry does select all of the users messages - however within the specific conversation it selects the first ever message.

Comment: Yes, and what happens when you use the slightly different query proposed in the answer?

Comment: i only receive a total of one conversations and the recent message within the conversation is still the first ever message.

Comment: i believe its because i have to make an order statement within the group statement, but i cant seem to figure out a way to do this.

Comment: Please could you clarify. Are you expecting one row or many rows in the result? Is message_id the column name you want to sort on to determine the most recent message? (Is it the primary key?)

Comment: Yes ofc. I have a primary table with a message_id (primary), message_receiver, message_sender. I want all the possible results where the two users and sending a message to each other. So for each "conversations" there should be selected a conversation. This is found by the group of message_receiver. But when i get Conversation 1, Conversation 2, Conversation 3 the messages within the conversation is the first message the two users ever wrote to each other. i hope this helps. thank you

Comment: Got it. I have rewritten the answer, please test.

Comment: Error near: 'AS SUBQUERY1 ) ORDER BY UM.MESSAGE_ID DESC' AT LINE 6

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90075/discussion-between-steve-e-and-heretohelpphp).

Comment: perfect solution. a simple (s) in user(s)_messages made the error. thank you for the code!

Answer (score 0):

Order by id that increments with every insert.